# Visual Studio Code adds a line break after < and {

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code worked fine till I upgraded macOS to Catalina 10.15.6. After restarting mac, Visual Studio Code always puts a line break after < and { in js files.

```
<
    div className = "event-form" >
<
    div className = "event-form-header" >
<
    h4 > {
            userName
        }
        's event</h4> <
        hr className = "event-form__hr" / >
<
    /div>
```

I updated Visual Studio Code to 1.48.2 but didn't help. It failed compilation because the following format is not allowed:

```
<
    /div>
```

Comment: The content seems written in html not in js